# VMware total memory, consumed memory & available memory

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I've checked the summary and performance of

1. total memory
2. consumed memory
3. available memory

in a cluster of 3 hosts. The values shown in vsphere don't make sense to me.  Could someone explain what these values mean?  What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you're looking at. We may be able to explain that with context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to quote from VMware's [online documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/memory_counters.html):

> The VMkernel maps **guest physical memory** to **machine memory**.
>   However, because of the VMkernel’s unique memory-management
>   techniques, such as ballooning, memory-sharing, swapping, and other
>   techniques, guest physical memory-to-machine memory mapping does not
>   have a 1:1 correspondence. Specifically, the VMkernel can:
>
> - Map multiple regions of guest physical memory to a single region of machine memory (which the VMkernel does for memory sharing among
>     virtual machines)
> - Leave specific regions of guest physical memory and machine memory unmapped (which the VMkernel does during swapping and ballooning)

In other words, those values won't map one-to-one because of the way VMWare handles memory.